# Unable save data using sqlserverce

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce, insert-update

I'm trying to save data using local database (**SQLServerCe**) with below code

```
Private Sub save_setup()
    Dim msg As String
    Try
        If setupupdate = True Then
            sql = "UPDATE connection_setup SET datasource_name = '" & t_hostname.Text & "'" & _
                  ", database_name = '" & t_dbname.Text & "', username = '" & t_uid.Text & "'" & _
                  ", password = '" & t_passwd.Text & "'"
            msg = "Updated"
        Else
            sql = "INSERT INTO connection_setup(datasource_name, database_name, username, password)" & _
                  " VALUES('" & t_hostname.Text & "', '" & t_dbname.Text & "','" & t_uid.Text & "'" & _
                  " , '" & t_passwd.Text & "') "
            msg = "Inserted"
        End If

        If conCe.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conCe.Open()
        End If

        comCe = New SqlCeCommand(sql, conCe)
        comCe.ExecuteNonQuery()

        comCe.Dispose()
        conCe.Close()
        MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Connection Setup")
    Catch
        MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Connection Setup")
    End Try
End Sub
```

When i push button save, which is run code above, no issue on the process but the data is not saved.
I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with .NET Framework 4.
Any idea what the cause and its solution?

FYI:
If I ran insert/update data by SQL query, the data can be saved.

Comment: Did you check fór a copy of your database file in the bin/debug folder?

Comment: What should I check? @ErikEJ
The database copy is there, under the bin/debug folder

Comment: Open it and confirm it contains the expected data!

Comment: Yes, it contains the data. How I move it into the original database? @ErikEJ

Answer (score 0):

Your data is saved in a copy of the database in the bin/debug folder. Simplest fix is to specify a full path in the connection string during development.

Comment: Here my code:
    query_con = "DATA SOURCE=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Database1.sdf;password="

Any wrong in my path? @ErikEJ